# How to connect to a https URL using HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, android, https, ssl-certificate, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to post some data to a https URL, so I used the code I found in http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html:

```
                KeyStore keyStore = ...;
                String algorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
                TrustManagerFactory tmf =TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
                tmf.init(keyStore);

                SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

The problem is, that I am getting this exception:

```
    Exception : java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

EXTRA INFO1:
I can post successfully to the https: address without doing anything extra from my laptop's Terminal, this is the printout of the connection's verbose:

```
== Info: Connected to cloud.someserver.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
== Info: TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
== Info: Server certificate: cloud.someserver.com
== Info: Server certificate: StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
== Info: Server certificate: StartCom Certification Authority
```

EXTRA INFO2: This is the printout I get from console when I execute "openssl s_client -connect cloud.myserver.com:80" :

CONNECTED(00000003)
77152:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:618:
Joshs-MacBook-Pro:~ JoshDBS$ openssl s_client -connect cloud.myserver.com:8080
connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=61
Joshs-MacBook-Pro:~ JoshDBS$ openssl s_client -connect cloud.myserver.com:81
connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=61
Joshs-MacBook-Pro:~ JoshDBS$ openssl s_client -connect cloud.myserver.com:80

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
77155:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:618:
Joshs-MacBook-Pro:~ JoshDBS$ openssl s_client -connect cloud.myserver.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /C=ES/CN=cloud.myserver.com/emailAddress=postmaster@myserver.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=ES/CN=cloud.myserver.com/emailAddress=postmaster@myserver.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=ES/CN=cloud.myserver.com/emailAddress=postmaster@myserver.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=ES/CN=cloud.myserver.com/emailAddress=postmaster@myserver.com
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGQTCCBSmgAwIBAgIHBcg1dAivUzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBjDELMAkGA1UE
(Lots of alphanumeric characters here)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=ES/CN=cloud.myserver.com/emailAddress=postmaster@myserver.com
issuer=/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2304 bytes and written 328 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: B67EED30382BE22A81F86884646480E967662A1559CA791B1B4DA8F06EDC
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: DE439EC4BEA0AA6E9B15836AD33DB46105D1A27544E0570E8EFF50D3BEF8F0725FC1A34343495D5ADAE192DD09838
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1450886131
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
closed
```

What value do I need to assign to the keystore instead of those three dots (...) and where do I get it from?

How can I POST data using HttpsURLConnection? (I can already post to simple http: URLs)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
```

Also, what URL are you trying to access? It might not be in the Android's DataStore of trusted certificates, which means you'll have to do a bit more work to add a certificate to the DataStore yourself.

Let me know if you are still stuck and we'll further debug your issue.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got the same result, I also added some Extra info to the question that you may find useful. I am trying to connect to a development https url address, that is surely not in Android's data store.

Comment: Try the following: openssl s_client -connect host:port. Do you get a certificate back from the server?

Comment: Hi, @C2H6O I have retaken the issue after the holidays, I have added the info about the certificate I get back to the question. I didnt configure anything on my laptop, the Terminal just accepts the certificate with the command you told me. I guess I need to do something else in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the SSL Certification validation [as explained here](http://tutoref.com/how-to-disable-ssl-certificat-validation-in-java/).
This is recommended only for development purposes, not in a production environment. in a production environment you must install the convenient certificates.

```
 TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
          public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
           return null;
          }
          @Override
          public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
           throws CertificateException {}

          @Override
          public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {}

          }
     };

  SSLContext sc=null;
  try {
   sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  try {
   sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
  } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

  // Create all-trusting host name verifier
  HostnameVerifier validHosts = new HostnameVerifier() {
  @Override
  public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
   return true;
  }
  };
  // All hosts will be valid
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(validHosts);
```